# Powershell find the lowest string

Tags: arrays, list, powershell, max, min

I printed all employees name in Powershell but now I need to get the longest name between all employees so which code should I write to get??

I have tried this but its only print for me employees length name

foreach ($user in $AzADUsers){
$UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName

```
  if ($UserPrincipalName -ceq $workemail){

   $dp =  $user.DisplayName 
  ( $dp |  Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum.ToString().Length

    Write-Host  " $dp  "
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sort-Object` to sort the user objects in `$AzADUsers` based on the length of the display name - then you can simply pick the last entry to get one with the longest name:

```
$UsersSorted = $AzADUsers |Sort-Object {$_.DisplayName.Length}

# Index -1 gives us the last item in the array
$longestUserName = $UsersSorted[-1].DisplayName
```

Comment: what if I want to find the longest givenName + surname not the display name

Comment: `Sort-Object {($_.GivenName + $_.Surname).Length}`

Comment: and when i want to get the shortest name it will be the same just I change the number between [ ]?

Comment: @h_akm yep, just change the index from `-1` to `0` to get the first item

Comment: * is this correct ? *      $longestUserName = $UsersSorted[-1].GivenName + $UsersSorted[-1].Surname   **because the output is wrong**

Comment: @h_akm I don't know what that means, I can't see your screen :) Does it yield a result that's shorter than you expected?

Comment: yes it output for me a short name not the longest one

Comment: @h_akm Even when you sort on `{ ($_.GivenName + $_.Surname).Length }`? That's odd, `Sort-Object` always defaults to ascending ordering...